# SpriteKit contact detection has slight delay

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm creating a small game where the ball needs to bounce on the upper, left and right wall, while it should stop as soon as it touches the floor.

I already have a working contact-detection code and delegate that is called in the correct situation and with the correct timing.
Creating a small circle in the collision point found in the `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` creates the node in the correct position.

In the same method I call `ball.physicsBody?.velocity = .zero` and `ball.position = contact.contactPoint` and the ball correctly stops. The problem is that sometimes the ball stops a frame too late, after it's already bounced off the floor.

The ball has a restitution of 1 because I would like it to bounce without slowing down, except when touching the floor.

I have already tried to set the position to zero, the velocity to zero, its `isDynamic` attribute to false. Each of these tries does what it's supposed to do, but sometimes it happens a frame too late.
Both the ball and the floor have the `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` property set to `true`.

If I try to add some artificial delay, the contact method is called again (breaking part of the gameplay).

Here is the code of my ball node:

```swift
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(imageNamed: "earth")

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 12.5)
        physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Masks.ball
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Masks.floor
        physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        physicsBody?.friction = 0
        physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    }
}
```

and here is the code for my `didBegin` method:

```swift
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    ball.physicsBody?.velocity = .zero
    ball.position = contact.contactPoint
}
```

I would expect the ball to stop while still touching the floor, and not a frame after it's already bounced off.

Comment: You do not want your ball set to contact point, that puts the center of the ball to the line it made contact with, and your other physics is pushing it back